# Can we use the same packagename in android with Different case?

Tags: android, keystore, case-sensitive, package-name

I had an app in the google play store and I lost the keystore file. So now i am trying to delete the previous app and create a new one with same characters but different case.Is it possible?That is if the previous package name is "com.example.MyandroidApp" now i want to make it "com.example.MyANDROIDApp"?

Answer (score -1):

> No you can't. 
>   However your package name is case sensitive

Comment: Why is this in a blockquote?

Comment: @VenomVender thanks,but when i deleted the previous app ,i could upload that in play store with different case.